# portal:actionURL Spring MVC Portlet

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, spring-mvc, portlet

I am trying to create a actionUrl using the following code

```
<portlet:actionURL var="actionUrl"><portlet:param name='action' value='viewModules' /></portlet:actionURL>
```

and map that onto a spring controller

However the controller does not respond as the generated url's ampersands are encoded

e.g.

```
<snip>&amp;p_p_lifecycle=1&amp;p_p_state=normal&amp;p_p_mode=view&amp;p_p_col_id=column-1&amp;p_p_col_count=2</snip>
```

If I unencode and paste into the browser this works

I have added 
portlet.url.escape.xml=false
to portal-ext.properties but to no available

Could any please point me in the right direction

Many Thanks

Comment: The encoded ampersands should not be a problem since it really is the correct way to represent an url. Do you use actionUrl in a form action perhaps?

Comment: Yes - thanks for the reply. I use it in a form

Answer (score 0):

In a form action I use:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="send" escapeXml="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however this gives this error
Attribute escapeXml invalid for tag actionURL according to TLD
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)

Comment: For posterity, the "escapeXml invalid for tag" error was likely because you were not building against the Portlet 2.0 version of pluto-taglib.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the scoop on this issue from a colleague...

Apparently Portlet 2.0 changed the status quo for URLs and declared they must be escaped by default.  (Previously there was no rule, and it seems several portals implemented them unescaped.)  Escaped URLs work just fine in the majority of cases... but not in every case (e.g. when used in JavaScript).

For those cases the 2.0 version of the  tags offers the `escapeXml="false"` attribute.  Here's an example:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="enterAlertUrl" escapeXml="false">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="enterAlert"/>
    <portlet:param name="studentId" value="STUDENTID"/>
    <portlet:param name="courseId" value="COURSEID"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
```

This renderURL will give you a URL string *without* URL-encoded ampersands between parameters.

Comment: Excellent thanks for following up way down the line Now to remember where it cased me the issue;-)